# Run ASP code online

Tags: asp-classic

I am new to ASP and have just started to learn it. I am looking for some websites, where I can execute my ASP code online. I looked at `ideone`, `codepad`, `compile online`, etc. But, they do not support ASP. Can anyone tell me about an online compiler for executing ASP code?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Buy some shared web hosting that supports Classic ASP and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to be able to run it online? Microsoft offer WebMatrix for free which has a built in server and should support Classic ASP, then it will run directly on your machine.

http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/

Comment: Note

WebMatrix is no longer recommended as an integrated development environment for ASP.NET Web Pages. Use Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

You can install this open source project by Li Chen.

https://weblogs.asp.net/lichen/asp-classic-compiler-is-now-open-source